# Can I use Jenkins on docker, integrate it to a private github repo and have jenkins use the host to run docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am a noob in programming in general, but more even so with jenkins. I have a fastapi app and postgres as db, both running on distinct docker containers and a repo at github with the code. Now I am trying to use jenkins to automate tests every time I push new code to github, but I am thinking what I want to do is not really practical or possible, which is: use Jenkins on docker, integrate it to a private github repo and have jenkins use the host to run docker. At first I was thinking in using a Docker-in-docker so that the jenkins instance would be in a container that could run docker, but I decide to follow the approach bellow because of [this article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

So this is the jenkins istance:

```
docker run -d --name jenkins-docker --restart=on-failure 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home 
-p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000 jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

and it is already integrated with github, through the use a github app, so every time a push to the repo a job starts.

Now, this is the jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
         sh 'docker compose -p testing -f docker/testing.yml up -d'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/vlep-pipeline_main@tmp/durable-9098aec0/script.sh: 1: docker: not found
```

Shouldn't it find the command since it is running with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`?

And, supposing the issue above is solved, would jenkins be able to build and run the images this way?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mapping the sockets is not enough. I still need to have docker binary installed and in my case docker compose plugin as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).